# Execution failed for task ':audioplayers_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':audioplayers_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Couldn't read file content: 'D:\Flutter Projects\xylophone_app_flutter\build\audioplayers_android\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\xyz\luan\audioplayers\LogLevel.class'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.